# How to get token returned in response body (of authentication web service) using RestTemplate?

Tags: android, spring

im using RestTemplate to call the authenticate web service and POST username and password,i need in return to get the token from response body but i can't find a clear way to do it..Here is my code

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("Content-Type","application/json");
requestHeaders.add("Accept", "application/json");
requestHeaders.add("Authorization", auth_token);
final String url = "http://192.168.1.3:18080/api/authenticate";
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("password",password);
map.add("username",username);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity= new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, requestHeaders);
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url,entity,String.class);
return response;
```

and this is the response body that i need to get the token from it:[web service response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcoTB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there, at the moment your code gets the whole JSON response as a string:

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(url,entity,String.class); 
// {"id_token": "blahblahblah"}
```

Instead you can either transform to a Map and take the correct value:

```
Map<String, Object> response3 = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, Map.class);
return response3.get("id_token") 
// blahblahblah
```

or create a class:

```
public class AuthResponse {

    @JsonProperty( "id_token" )
    private String idToken;

    public String getIdToken() {
        return idToken;
    }

    public void setIdToken(String idToken) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
    }
}
```

and transform that:

```
AuthResponse response4 = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, AuthResponse.class);
return response4.getIdToken();
// blahblahblah
```

Comment: Thank you, actually i found the solution today by creating a class as u mentionned! it works great :)